# Formula for the total no of square submatrixes in a matrix

Tags: math, matrix

In a matrix of size r * c, is there any formula to find the total no of square submatrixes in it? For example :

[ 4, 4, 4, 4

4, 4, 4, 4

4, 4, 4, 4 ]

There are 20 square submatrixes in it which is 12(all individual elements are square submatrixes themselves) + 6 (square submatrixes of size 2 * 2) + 2 (square submatrixes of size 3 * 3). Is there any formula to calculate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the rectangular matrix of dimension  `m x n` (let's assume than `n >= m`) there are

```
K = m x (m+1) x (2m+1)/6 + (n-m) x m x (m+1)/2
```

square submatrices of the dimension `1 <= k <= m`
If you are not interested in `1 x 1` matrices substract `m x n` from `K`